# Links in page don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, href

I have problem with link in one page. It work when i want scroll down, but when i want scroll up it stay in the same place. This is part of code:

```
(function($){
/* Store the original positions */
var d1 = $('.one');
var d1orgtop = d1.position().top;
var d2 = $('.two');
var d2orgtop = d2.position().top;
var d3 = $('.three');
var d3orgtop = d3.position().top;
var d4 = $('.four');
var d4orgtop = d4.position().top;

/* respond to the scroll event */
$(window).scroll(function(){
    /* get the current scroll position */
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();

    /* change classes based on section positions */
    if (st >= d1orgtop) {
        d1.addClass('latched');
    } else {
        d1.removeClass('latched');
    }
    if (st >= d2orgtop) {
        d2.addClass('latched');
    } else {
        d2.removeClass('latched');
    }
    if (st >= d3orgtop) {
        d3.addClass('latched');
    } else {
        d3.removeClass('latched');
    }
    if (st >= d4orgtop) {
        d4.addClass('latched');
    } else {
        d4.removeClass('latched');
    }
});
```

And example in JSFIDDLE [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/masza/nft4oeab/)

When i click href on top of the page it scroll down. But when i click href on the bottom, nothing happens. Where is my fault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/nft4oeab/2/)**

Because of your style `position:fixed` on `.latched` class. You remove it you fix it but yea it effects the original functionality as per my visualization. so as an alternative, I have below `jquery` hack which actually functions as required.

```
$('a[href="#intro"]').on('click',function(){
  $(d1,d2,d3,d4).removeClass('latched');  
  //on click of #intro element you just remove latched class from all the elements
})
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: But what if i want to use some navigation like topbar or sth? It unfortunately don't work so well then...

Comment: Can you show a demo for same in fiddle? Not getting exact picture of what you are asking for!

Comment: Nevermind, i found better solution using jquery function ScrollTo() ;) Anyway thank you for feedback!

Answer (score 3):

I'd a similar issue, and for some other reasons I used a function to set scroll to page.

I've tested with your example and worked fine, see the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nft4oeab/3/

The function is:

```
function scrollToAnchor(aid){
    var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But it work only because href"#" not because script. It don't work when I want use it in navbar or sth like this.